# Finding size of perfect quad tree

Tags: c++, tree, size, binary-tree

I need to find the size of a perfect quad tree.
This means I have 1 root node that splits into 4 nodes that splits into 4 nodes etc.

so a quad tree of height 1 would be size 1
height 2 = size 5  (1 + 4)
height 3 = size 21 (1 + 4 + 16)
height 4 = size 85 (1 + 4 + 16 + 64)

etc..

I know that the size of a perfect binary tree can be found with: size = 2^(height+1)-1
So I believe that a similar equation exists for quad tree.

So what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum).  So the relevant formula is:

```
S = a * (1 - r^n) / (1 - r)
```

where `a` is the first value, `r` is the common ratio, `n` is the number of terms, and `^` denotes "to-the-power-of".

Answer (score 3):

For a quad tree the algorithm is

```
((4^depth)-1)/3
```

For example with depth 3 you get

```
(64-1)/3 = 21
```

and if you count three layers you get

```
1 + 4 + 16 = 21
```

In my implementation I have even divided it into two arrays
where the size for all nodes that arent leave nodes is

```
((4^(depth-1))-1)/3
```

and leave nodes is

```
4^(depth-1)
```

I do these calculations at compile time with meta programming for pow, and a template argument for the depth. So i just allocate my nodes in two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone will need a code sample *(in swift3)*

```
public func tileCount(forLevelRange levelRange: Range<UInt>) -> UInt64 {

   var tileCount: UInt64 = 0
   for level in levelRange.lowerBound ..< levelRange.upperBound {
       tileCount += UInt64(pow(Double(1 << level), 2) )
   }

   return tileCount
}
```